# How to parse this yaml file in bash to get specific values?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, yaml

My output.yml returned by aws cli looks like this:

```
ARN: random-arn
CreatedDate: 'some-random-date`
Name: random-name
SecretString: '{"Password":"fake-password","Hostname":"fake-host","Username":"fake-username"}'
VersionId: random-version
VersionStages:
- AWSCURRENT
```

I want to parse and fetch the Password and Username from the above file in bash to create another yaml file with below data:

```
Instance:
  Password: fake-password
  Username: fake-username
```

How can I do this in shell script?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].  You can use `grep` to isolate the line you want (SecretString), and `cut`, `awk`, `sed` to extract the parts you want out of the line.  Get started, do some research, ask again with a specific question.

Comment: You can parse it yourself, or use a tool like [yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/).